# Rewrite Spark Java Application in Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to "convert" my Spark Application, which is written in Java into Scala.
Because I'm new to Scala and Spark's Scala API, I don't know how to write this "transformToPair" function in Scala:

Java:

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Boolean> outlierPairDStream = avgAll1h.union(avgPerPlug1h).transformToPair(findOutliersPerComparisonFunction);

*** FUNCTION ***

private static Function<JavaPairRDD<String,Float>, JavaPairRDD<String,Boolean>> findOutliersPerComparisonFunction = new Function<JavaPairRDD<String,Float>, JavaPairRDD<String,Boolean>>() {
    public JavaPairRDD<String, Boolean> call(JavaPairRDD<String, Float> v1) throws Exception {

        float avgOfAll;
        if(v1.count() > 0) {
            avgOfAll = v1.filter(new Function<Tuple2<String,Float>, Boolean>() {
                public Boolean call(Tuple2<String, Float> v1) throws Exception {
                    return v1._1().equals("all");
                }
            }).values().collect().get(0);
        } else {
            avgOfAll = 0.0f;
        }

        final float finalAvg = avgOfAll;

        JavaPairRDD<String, Boolean> rddBool = v1.mapValues(new Function<Float, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(Float v1) throws Exception {
                return v1 > finalAvg;
            }
        });


        return rddBool.filter(new Function<Tuple2<String,Boolean>, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(Tuple2<String, Boolean> v1) throws Exception {
                return !v1._1().equals("all");
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Here my attempt with Scala:

```
val outlierPairDStream = avgAll1h.union(avgPerPlug1h).transform{rdd => 
  var avgOfAll = 0.0

  if(rdd.count() > 0) {
    avgOfAll = rdd.filter({case (k, v) => (k == "all")}).map({case (k, v) => v}).collect()(0)
  }

  val finalAvg = avgOfAll

  val rddBool = rdd.map({case(k, v) => (k, v > finalAvg)})

  val rddNew = rddBool.filter({case(k, v) => (k != "all")})
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
<console>:281: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[?]
       }
       ^
```

Can someone help me? How can I return the "rddNew" DStream?

If I say

```
return rddNew
```

at the end of the "transform" function, I get the following error:

```
<console>:293: error: return outside method definition
       return rddNew
       ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually return the last value, e.g. like that:

```
val outlierPairDStream = avgAll1h.union(avgPerPlug1h).transform{rdd => 
  var avgOfAll = 0.0

  if(rdd.count() > 0) {
    avgOfAll = rdd.filter({case (k, v) => (k == "all")}).map({case (k, v) => v}).collect()(0)
  }

  val finalAvg = avgOfAll

  val rddBool = rdd.map({case(k, v) => (k, v > finalAvg)})

  val rddNew = rddBool.filter({case(k, v) => (k != "all")})

  rddNew
}
```

Or simply skip defining the variable altogether:

```
val outlierPairDStream = avgAll1h.union(avgPerPlug1h).transform{rdd => 
  var avgOfAll = 0.0

  if(rdd.count() > 0) {
    avgOfAll = rdd.filter({case (k, v) => (k == "all")}).map({case (k, v) => v}).collect()(0)
  }

  val finalAvg = avgOfAll

  val rddBool = rdd.map({case(k, v) => (k, v > finalAvg)})

  rddBool.filter({case(k, v) => (k != "all")})
}
```

A bit more Scala-like could be:

```
val outlierPairDStream = avgAll1h.union(avgPerPlug1h).transform{rdd => 

  val finalAvg = if(rdd.count() > 0) {
    rdd.filter({case (k, v) => (k == "all")}).map({case (k, v) => v}).collect()(0)
  } else { 0.0 }

  val rddBool = rdd.map({case(k, v) => (k, v > finalAvg)})

  rddBool.filter({case(k, v) => (k != "all")})
}
```

Comment: This did it for me, I just tried to use the row "rddNew" WITHOUT the RETURN keyword, and it works now! You saved my day, thank you!